# Summing data in a column by a unique identifier in another column in Excel

Tags: excel

In my spreadsheet I want to sum up the number of sessions for each particular Tier group.

For example, I want to know how many standard sessions there are total. Is there a simple formula for this, or am I asking too much of excel?

[Click here for image](http://www.supermotors.net/getfile/987425/fullsize/712013-112154-am.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Try SUMIF, e.g.

`=SUMIF(G:G,"Standard",E:E)`